# Can not access a certain HTTPS domain. Very weird issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, http, https

I'm having a very weird issue with a certain HTTPS site.  I have no crazy network setup or firewalls.  Just computers behind a cable modem.  I feel dumb but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I'm about ready to just reinstall the OS (Windows 8 standard non-domain environment).  When accessing on chrome it just hangs on establishing secure connection.  An ERR_TIMED_OUT is returned

- All HTTPS sites work but a certain one (it's a standard internet site)
- This happens on all browsers (Chrome, IE, FF)
- If I put another computer on the network it can access the site just fine so it's not a network issue.
- I put the affected PC on another network and it still can not access the site leading me to believe the computer is the issue.
- There is no HTTP version.  I made a raw request on port 80 and a Location header is returned redirecting me to the HTTPS version.
- Wireshark shows me sending a Client HELLO
- I tried disabling all AV and Firewalls to no success
- There is no proxy required.  I tried checking and unchecking "Automatically detect proxy settings"
- I tried accessing the site in a VM installed on the affected computer.  The same thing is happening on the VM.
- Yes, I tried rebooting!!!

Comment: why is the "site" a secret?

Comment: Verify the SSL Protocols of the website match the supported Protocol of your browser.  Without specific information ( for instance the website in question ) we might not be able to help you.  You have tried everything I would have suggested personally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the possibility that it has nothing at all to do with your computer?  Maybe it's the server on the other end.

Try accessing the same site from a phone or device that's not on your current network.  There isn't much we can do.

Comment: Read the conditions.  Other computers on my network work with that site.  My computer on another network does NOT work with that site

Comment: Download yourself a linux livecd, burn it to a disk and boot from the CD.  Most of them have a browser.  If you can access it from the browser on the livecd, but not your windows installation -- well, i think that pretty much speaks to a faulty windows installation.